# PHP Division results in automatically rounded up number

Tags: php, rounding, division

I have a simple division:

72 / 193

Excel is giving me result of

0.373056994818653

While PHP round it up to

0.373056994819

My question is - how can I make PHP to give me the exact number instead of a rounded up one?

Comment: What PHP version do you use? What OS do you use? 32/64 bit? Personally I get `float(0.37305699481865)` on [codepad](http://codepad.org/Z2uT6xEy)

Comment: You should look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Comment: check your configuration `echo ini_get('precision')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a question of being 'exact' or not, it is about precision.  [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=72+%2F+193) has a much larger precision for your answer.

You need to change the [precision of your php configuration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) to suit how many units you need after the decimal.  I cannot find the largest precision PHP has to offer, but I'm sure there is a limit.

Comment: Great stuff, your response has given me not only an answer why but also a permanent solution. After changing precision from 12 to 15 in php.ini, I'm now getting the exact same figure as in Excel. Thanks everyone for their help though, too!

Answer (score 1):

The exact number for that is an infinite decimal. You can never get a complete absolute value for that, because that would require infinite memory, something that we sadly do not have access to.

Take a look at [bcdiv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php), which allows for very long ints and floating point numbers

For all practical intents and purposes, however, if two numbers are within 1*10<sup>-8</sup> or so, you should be able to consider them equal

You can do this like this:

```
if(abs($num1-$num2)<=1e-8){
    echo "They are equal";
}
```